# Django Rest API for simple python dictionary

Tags: python, django, api

I'm new to Django and I want to make a simple restful API that will return the python dictionary in JSON format upon calling it from the postman. I have set up my project folder and have installed the RestfulAPI frame and also I have configured my settings.py
For example,
In dictionary.py I have the following code

```
dataDictionary = { 
            'hello': 'World', 
            'geeks': 'forgeeks', 
            'ABC': 123, 
            456: 'abc', 
            14000605: 1, 
            'list': ['geeks', 4, 'geeks'], 
            'dictionary': {'you': 'can', 'send': 'anything', 3: 1} 
        }
```

and I want to return this dict upon calling it from Postman by entering the URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/getdata/ by using Method POST.
I have attached the Django APP VIEW picture.
[Django_APP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYUGy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to import several things to configure a basic API view:

```
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, renderer_classes, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

@api_view(['POST', 'GET'])
@renderer_classes((JSONRenderer,))
@permission_classes([AllowAny,])
def sample_view(request):
    dataDictionary = { 
        'hello': 'World', 
        'geeks': 'forgeeks', 
        'ABC': 123, 
        456: 'abc', 
        14000605: 1, 
        'list': ['geeks', 4, 'geeks'], 
        'dictionary': {'you': 'can', 'send': 'anything', 3: 1} 
    } 
    return Response(dataDictionary)
```

Notice the three decorators used. `@render_classes` taking tuple with `JSONRenderer` is used to render json, `@api_view` is used to specify that this is an API view that gets `POST` and `GET` as legitimate requests, and `@permission_classes` taking `[AllowAny,]` - takes the list of access permissions.
If you want to restrict, you can specify `IsAuthenticated` or any other.
This is a very basic view example that you can use as a starting point. Of course you need to register it with your `urls.py` providing a path.

Comment: Is there any way that instead of writing this whole code in views.py, I can write this code in a different file for example dictionary.py, and save this file under the same project folder? Like request comes in the sample_view method and from here it goto dictionary.py file and takes the datadictionary variable and comes back to sample_view and return the Response >?

Comment: @MuhammadUsman As long as your view can be imported in *urls.py* it does not matter where it's declared, it just needs to be imported and registered. It's just more convenient to keep all views in a single place so the code gets cleaner and more organzied.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. You can do it using `JsonResponse` method

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse

def api_test(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        data = {"key":"value"}
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

> 2. or You can also do it using `Response` method, but with Response you must have to use `api_view` decorator

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view 
from rest_framework.response import Response

@api_view(('GET',)) 
def api_test(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        data = {"key":"value"}
        return Response(data)
```